# ¿Cómo generar número aleatorio en ensamblador?

Tags: ensamblador, programación-bajo-nivel

Soy nuevo en ensamblador, me gustaría saber como generar números aleatorios en un rango determinado, por ejemplo entre 0 y 25.

Comment: Mira en este link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855817/generating-a-random-number-within-range-of-0-9-in-x86-8086-assembly , de pronto te puede orientar

Comment: ¿Qué ensamblador: 8085 u 8086?

Comment: Prueba con esto https://students.cs.byu.edu/~cs224ta/references/HowTos/HowTo_Random.php

Answer (score 3):

Para generar números pseudo-aleatorios ( aleatorios aleatorios, nunca lo será), más aún en ensamblador necesitarás usar polinomios generadores de números aleatorios (en algunos sitios les llaman RNG = Random Number Generator)

Es decir, una estructura de datos que se realimenta con el último valor que ha sacado , para sacar el siguiente y que asegura ciertas condiciones de aleatoriedad. Cosas importantes a tener en cuenta? Que el generador es cíclico, es decir serás más o menos largo, pero al final acabará a volver a generar la misma tira de números aleatorios. Ya que el valor que saquemos depende del valor anterior, es importante que la raíz de nuestro generador siempre cambie al iniciar nuestra ejecución ( típica mente se usa el valor del reloj si lo hubiera o bien algún tipo de puerta al aire del procesador )

En este campo está todo hecho y calculado y podrás encontrar 20k algoritmos de polinomios generadores cada uno con sus características (más amplitud de aleatoriedad, más uniformidad en la distribución, más velocidad en la ejecución, etc..) En esta web tiene una lista de generadores sencillos con su código: http://paraisomat.ii.uned.es/paraiso/cripto.php?id=macros. El código es C pero es trivial pasarlo a asm, creo que puedes hacerlo tu.

En la wikipedia hay un artículo al respecto que tal vez te oriente un poco mejor: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generador_de_n%C3%BAmeros_aleatorios

Cualquier cosa ya lo sabes